Reclaiming Shortcuts taken by now removed Windows Bloatware
I got rid of a lot of Bloatware that Win 11 ships with by Clean My PC, however the shortcuts these things have so rudely taken are still being inaccessible.
Is there any way how to let these shortcuts through?

Do you mean file associations?

No, for instance Game-Bar app has Win+G shortcut, after removing the app, the shortcut is unusable - i.e. it can be viewed in key event logger and thus assigned to anything

then you should [edit] your question to clarify that you mean keyboard shortcuts, specifically those assigned to programs built into the system. There are many different types of "shortcut", for example the type of shortcut that links to a file or program

Removing the game bar application does not necessarily mean that the shortcut is being captured by that application. It may well be that the shortcut is captured by a permanently running program such as Explorer or some other system application that just knows how to run Game Bar when the keyboard shortcut is pressed. Windows is a large amount of intermingled software and one visible (Game Bar) thing is not necessarily the same as the thing that runs it.

“Clean My PC” is the absolute last application I would ever run on my machine, there is no telling, how it removes these applications. I suspect the fact the keyboard shortcuts are still being captured suggests the tool did not in fact remove them properly

Removing bloatware completely should have also removed the keyboard shortcuts, in most cases. If they're still not available after rebooting, then use a tool such as Wise Disk Cleaner to remove them. For that utility, select Common Cleaner > Windows System > Invalid Shortcuts.
Nirsoft's HotKeysList can list some of the hotkeys, but I've not found a way to list all. Some code that worked on older versions of Windows fails on Windows 10 and 11 to list anything.
That said, there are applications such as AutoHotkey and Clavier+ that in many cases can reassign or override the Windows hotkeys. One great advantage is having all hotkeys listed in a single place, as shown below.

Note that MS has made some shortcuts difficult or impossible to remove or overwrite. Examples are WindowsShiftAltCtrl, which opens a browser tab to Microsoft 365, and WindowsShiftAltCtrlL, which opens a browser tab to Linkedin. sigh

Clavier+ looks like useful tool i did not know, I know I can remap these keys with AHK, but it will then make other shortcut unusable
